# Android xml shape fills the whole background

Tags: android, xml, shapes

I made a shape for a custom button and it fills the whole background of the button instead of showing the shape.

This is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="ring"
            android:useLevel="false"
            android:thicknessRatio="0">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <size
                android:width="1dp"
                android:height="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="0.75dp" android:top="1dp" android:bottom="0.5dp" android:right="1.5dp">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="" android:pivotX="0%" android:pivotY="0%" android:toDegrees="0">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <size android:height="1dp" android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. For some reason when I use the code I posted in an Imageview it shows correctly, but if I try to use it for a background (doesn't matter if it is for an Imageview/button/etc it shows as a square.

The problem seemed to be that the Preview doesn't represent at all the shape as a background, so I had to check the layout all the time and do the changes depending on it, and not the preview.

This is the final code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <size
                android:width="5dp"
                android:height="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="8dp" android:top="30dp" android:bottom="8dp" android:right="30dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <size android:height="1dp" android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```